# How can I disable assigning ULA address for an interface?

Tags: linux, ipv6

How can I disable assigning ULA address for an interface?

I am getting prefix from the router, I just need the global v6 address to be assigned to the interface. I dont need ULA. Is there any way I can disable it?

I am using linux, Is there any sysctl parameter to do the same?

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which linux distribution, but it's not common to assign a ULA by defaul.  Are you sure this isn't being assigned by your (home?) router?

Comment: Yes, it is the router giving the prefix. But is there anyway I disable it from the client side? I cant change the router settings.

Comment: If this is causing a specific problem, you should add it in the question, in case a solution to fix the problem rather than to not add the address is found.